# changes in shell script does not refresh in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a shell script, called `startmq.sh`, to run activeMQ. However I changed the script, it did not refresh the changes at all.

Even I only wrote `echo "Hello World"`, it did not refresh and was trying to run activeMQ with wrong parameters.

Then, I copy `startmq.sh` to `abc.sh` and tried to run `abc.sh`. It showed `Hello World`.
Plus, I need to use that standard name `startmq.sh`.

Thanks.

Comment: are you running the right script? Check path. :)

Comment: are you sure you are running the same script? are you sure you save the new contents?

Comment: Are you changing the script on the same machine that runs the script? Caching on a larger network might case similar problems.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found out the problem source with the help of @donald123's and Ahmad-San's answers. I upgrade activemq 5.3.2. to 5.6.0. There is also one startmq.sh in 5.3.2/bin. That path is put into $PATH. So whenever i run startmq.sh in 5.6.0/bin, that is pointing to 5.3.2/bin instead of 5.6.0/bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can it be, that you have this script multiple on the server?

under bash do the following  **whereis** shows you the locations of the script(s) and **which** shows you witch script ist starting ...

```
   bash:# whereis startmq.sh 
   bash:# which startmq.sh
```

Comment: also, in bash, `type -a startmq.sh`

Answer (score 2):

There must be another copy of `startmq.sh` somewhere accessible due to its path being amongst the `PATH` enviroment variable.

Comment: This happened to me due testing in my home dir before moving the changes to `/usr/local/sbin/`